# Grid alternative in React Native

Tags: css, react-native, grid

So I am currently trying to create a filter that looks like books stacked, an example of what I want to achieve is provided in the link bellow:
https://dribbble.com/shots/19300443-Audiobook-App

I have tried implementing Grid but that appears to be incompatible with react native and is not working - advice would be highly appreciated!

This is my code:

```
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View, ImageBackground, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'

    import React, { useState } from 'react'
    import LibraryBookCard from '../components/libraryBookCard'
    import * as Font from 'expo-font';
    import { globalStyles } from '../utils/GlobalStyles';
    
    const LibraryScreen = () => {
      const [fontLoaded, setFontLoaded] = useState(false);
    
      const loadFonts = async () => {
        await Font.loadAsync({
          'Hensa': require('../assets/fonts/Hensa.ttf'),
        });
        setFontLoaded(true);
      };
    
      React.useEffect(() => {
        loadFonts();
      }, []);
    
      let dummyData = [
        {title: 'The Lighthouse', author: 'Jess Thompson', prompt: "Magic Waterfall", genre: 'Action'},
        {title: 'Growing Pains', author: 'Cassidy Hue', prompt: "Magic Bean", genre: 'Fantasy'},
        {title: 'Lovesick', author: 'Alexa Pea', prompt: "Tinder", genre: 'Romance'},
        {title: 'Masks and Muggles', author: 'Emma Haas', prompt: "Wizardry", genre: 'Fantasy'},
        {title: 'The Magician', author: 'Joshy B', prompt: "Thee Sword", genre: 'Fantasy'},
      ]
      const handleButtonPress = () => {
        console.log("pressed");
      }
    
      return (
        <ImageBackground
          source={require('../assets/bg/general.png')}
          style={styles.backgroundImage}
        >
          {fontLoaded && (
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.heading}>Library</Text>
              <Text style={styles.body}>Let’s find the perfect story for you.</Text>
    
    
              <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.book, styles.book1]}>
                <Text style={styles.bookText}>Book 1</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
    
              <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.book, styles.book2]}>
                <Text style={styles.bookText}>Book 2</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
    
              <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.book, styles.book3]}>
                <Text style={styles.bookText}>Book 3</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
    
              
              <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.book, styles.book4]}>
                <Text style={styles.bookText}>Book 4</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
    
                        
              <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.book, styles.book5]}>
                <Text style={styles.bookText}>Book 5</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
    
              <Text style={styles.subHeading}>My Collection</Text>
              <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
                {dummyData.map((project, index) => (
                  <LibraryBookCard key={index} data={project}/>
                ))}
              </ScrollView>
            </View>
          )}
        </ImageBackground>
      )
    }
    
    export default LibraryScreen
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      backgroundImage: {
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
        paddingLeft: 30,
        paddingRight: 30,
        paddingBottom: 30,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        resizeMode: 'cover',
      },
      heading: {
        fontFamily: 'Hensa',
        fontSize: 52,
        color: 'white',
        width: 350,
        paddingTop: 65,
        paddingLeft: 20,
        lineHeight: 50,
      },
      body: {
        color: 'white',
        width: 350,
        paddingLeft: 20,
        paddingTop: 10,
        paddingBottom: 40,
      },
      scrollView: {
        height: 100,
      },
      subHeading:{
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight: 600,
        fontSize: 18,
        paddingLeft: 20,
    
      },
      buttonCcontainer: {
        flex: 1,
        display: 'grid',
        gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(5, 1fr)',
        gridTemplateRows: 'repeat(5, 1fr)',
        gridColumnGap: 0,
        gridRowGap: 0,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
      book1: {
        gridArea: '1 / 1 / 2 / 4',
        backgroundColor: '#B68C4C'
      },
      book2: {
        gridArea: '1 / 4 / 2 / 6',
        backgroundColor: '#9F3824'
      },
      book3: {
        gridArea: '2 / 1 / 5 / 2',
        backgroundColor: '#9F3824'
      },
      book4: {
        gridArea: '4 / 2 / 5 / 6',
        backgroundColor: '#6B8DFF'
      },
      book5: {
        gridArea: '2 / 2 / 4 / 6',
        backgroundColor: '#B68C4C'
      },
    });
```

Answer (score -5):

In React Native, you can achieve a grid effect by using the available layout components and applying appropriate styling. Here's a general approach to creating a grid layout in React Native:

Determine the Grid Structure: Decide on the number of columns and rows for your grid layout. This will help you determine the layout structure and sizing of the grid items.

Use Flexbox: Utilise Flexbox, a CSS layout system supported in React Native, to create the grid layout. Flexbox provides powerful tools for arranging items in a flexible manner.

Choose a Container Component: Select a suitable container component, such as View or ScrollView, to wrap your grid items. The choice depends on whether you want a scrollable grid or a fixed-size grid that fits within the screen.

Apply Styling: Apply appropriate styles to the container and grid items to achieve the desired grid effect. The key styles to consider include:

flexDirection: Set the flexDirection property of the container to 'row' or 'column', depending on whether you want a row-based or column-based grid.

flexWrap: If needed, set the flexWrap property to 'wrap' on the container to allow items to wrap to the next line or column.

flex: Assign a flex value to each grid item to control its relative size within the grid. For example, you can set flex: 1 on each grid item to make them equally sized, or assign different values to achieve custom sizing.

width and height: Use width and height properties to specify the dimensions of the grid items. You can set fixed sizes or utilize percentages or calculations based on the grid structure.

margin and padding: Apply appropriate margin and padding values to create spacing between grid items.

Additional styling properties: Consider other styling properties such as border, backgroundColor, and borderRadius to enhance the appearance of the grid.

Render Grid Items: Inside the container component, render the grid items using appropriate React Native components, such as View, TouchableOpacity, or custom components. You can map over a data array to dynamically generate the grid items or manually define them.

Customise Grid Item Content: Customise the content within each grid item according to your requirements. You can include images, text, buttons, or any other React Native components to represent the data or interactive elements within the grid.

By combining these steps and applying suitable styling, you can achieve a grid effect in React Native. Experiment with different layouts, styling properties, and components to create the desired grid layout for your application.

If you have a more complex case, please read this article - https://medium.com/@kalebjdavenport/how-to-create-a-grid-layout-in-react-native-7948f1a6f949

Comment: this chat-gpt like answers, just should be banned